# Can't copy a row from one database to another database on different server on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, copy

I was trying to copy a row from one database to another database on different server, here is the query:

```
set identity_insert ms_tpl on

INSERT ms_tpl select * from [10.24.0.2].[MILKP].[dbo].[ms_tpl] where [id] = 3076

set identity_insert ms_tpl off
```

when I pressed F5, I got error message like this:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ms_tpl' can only be specified when a column list is
>   used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Is there a mistake in my query? How to solve this problem?

more info: on database `ms_tpl`, there is one column called `id` with auto increment.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'ms_tpl' can only be specified **when a column list is used**  and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

don't use `*`. List your columns:

```
INSERT into ms_tpl (col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ... from ...
```

Comment: I've tried it I change the * with my columns list (all columns, without column "id") but I've got another error message like this: "Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'ms_tpl' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column."

Comment: But you want to override the `id` column. So list it in the query too.

Comment: INSERT ms_tpl select [id], [cUserId] ,[dLastUpdate] ,[ctipejual] ,[cKdUnitKey] ,[cKdGrupRelasi] ,[cKdRelasi] ,[cKdBarang] ,[bIsFluc] ,[cSatPeriod] ,[nHargaPeriod] ,[nHargaPeriodMax] ,[dTglValidAwal] ,[dTglValidAkhir] ,[cKdCurrency] ,[cSatuan1] ,[cSatuan2] ,[nHarga1] ,[nHarga2] ,[nRate] ,[bActive] ,[dTglInput] ,[cnodoc] ,[cKdwilayah] from [10.24.0.2].[MILKP].[dbo].[ms_tpl] where [id] = 3076

column `id` is `IDENTITY`

Comment: Try `insert into ms_tpl (id, [cUserId], ...) select ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add the columns list in the insert statement

```
INSERT ms_tpl column1, column2, ...
```

That will fix the issue

Comment: I've tried it I change the * with my columns list (all columns, without column "id") but I've got another error message like this: "Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'ms_tpl' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column."